# Simultaneous computation of the three Weber modular functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, computational-number-theory

Recall that the three classical Weber modular functions are defined by
$f(\tau)=e^{-\pi i/24}\eta((\tau+1)/2)/\eta(\tau)$,
$f_1(\tau)=\eta(\tau/2)/\eta(\tau)$, and
$f_2(\tau)=\sqrt{2}\eta(2\tau)/\eta(\tau)$.

I need to compute all three functions efficiently. Doing this as written
requires four evaluations of the Dedekind eta function. Using
the formula $f(\tau)f_1(\tau)f_2(\tau)=\sqrt{2}$ allows to reduce to
three evaluations. It seems reasonable to expect that one can reduce to
two evaluations, but I cannot seem to achieve this. Note that there are many
other relations such as $f_1^8+f_2^8=f^8$, but these seem to involve
square roots with an undetermined sign.

If this helps, I only need to evaluate $f^{24}+f_2^{24}$ and $f_1^6$, maybe this is
a simpler problem.